# Asking for microphone permission restarts Activity

Tags: flutter, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
```

I then call this inside one of the functions of MainActivity:

```
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO),
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO
            )
```

However, when I call it, instead of simply showing the microphone permission popup, it restarts the flutter activity and then shows the popup.

How can I make it just show the popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid asking the permission within the `MainActivity`. The easiest way would be to use the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) Flutter package and call it from your Flutter/Dart code.

```
if(await Permission.microphone.request().isGranted) {
  // use microphone
}
```

This will request the permission and execute the block within the curly braces if the user has granted it.

Comment: I just tried this and it still restarts the screen

Comment: Were there any other changes made to the native code, within the 'android' directory? In the manifest, MainActivity, ...